# Keras: Custom loss function: Dimension Issue (None, None)

Tags: keras, tensor, loss-function

I am constructing a neural network with Keras. And I need to define a simple custom loss function. However, I met dimension problem of y_True in creating a custom loss function.

I inserted print function in loss function to verify the dimension of y_true (target variable). It shows that dimension of y_true is (none, none), but it should be (none, 10). The dimension of y_pred is (none, 10).

Anyone can point out where is the mistake? Thanks a lot.

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

from keras import models
from keras import layers

network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(28 * 28,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

def customLoss(yTrue,yPred):
    print(yTrue)
    print(yPred)
    print(K.int_shape(yTrue))
    return K.dot(yTrue, yPred)  # K.mean(K.dot(yTrue,yPred), axis=-1)


network.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                loss=customLoss,
                metrics=['accuracy'])  # loss='categorical_crossentropy',

train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28 * 28))
train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255

test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28 * 28))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255

from keras.utils import to_categorical

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)



network.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=128)
```